# Are Android's "Full Disc Encryption" and "Storage Encryption" the same?

Tags: android, encryption

I am a bit confused about the different data storage encrpytion mechanisms of the Android platform. From what I understand:

- Full Disk Encryption affects the whole /data disk and can only be
  activated/deactivated by the user. (https://source.android.com/security/encryption/)
- Storage Encryption is data storage encryption on an app basis and can be activated/deactivated by the app developer via DeviceManager. (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setStorageEncryption%28android.content.ComponentName,%20boolean%29)

Is that correct or are Full Disk Encryption and Storage Encryption the same?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> are Full Disk Encryption and Storage Encryption the same?

Yes.

> Storage Encryption is data storage encryption on an app basis

No.

Comment: Thanks so far. Could you elaborate then on why/how there is an API method to enable StorageEncryption via code while on the other side it is a setting the user can enable/disable?

Comment: @Ascendor: Um, there are other things in Settings that can be controlled via APIs. Some of those APIs are unsecured (e.g., volume levels). Others are protected by permissions (e.g., clearing app data). AFAIK, the docs for `setStorageEncryption()` are wrong (or at least are wrong for Android 4.x devices), in that calling `setStorageEncryption()` does not actually do the encryption, but starts nagging the user to encrypt the device. Encrypting the device takes a while and really should be done while on a charger, which an API cannot handle itself.